# Subdifferential boundary conditions: Testing pointwise or with $L^2$ functions

Tags: convex-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Let $\phi \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be convex, proper and lower semi-continuous (lsc). Let $M$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

We can define a functional $\Phi \colon L^2(M) \to \mathbb R$ through
$$
  \Phi(v) = \begin{cases}
  \int_M \Phi(v(x))\,dx & \text{if $\Phi(v) \in L^1(M)$} \\
  \infty                & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$$

It is clear that this function is again convex and proper. That it is also lsc is shown in [Inequality Problems in Mechanic and Applications: Convex and Nonconvex Energy Functions](http://books.google.de/books?id=xWP5rrDdzMYC) (Proposition 3.3.1).

Even more is proved there, however. Assume $f \in L^2(M)$. Proposition 3.3.2 says that the following two statements are equivalent:

1. $\Phi(v) \ge \Phi(u) + \int_M f\cdot(v-u)$ for every $v \in L^2(M)$
2. We have $\phi(v) \ge \phi(u(x)) + f(x)[v-u(x)]$ for every $v \in \mathbb R^n$ almost everywhere in $M$.

It is mentioned at the end of the corresponding section (namely p.113), that this result does not hold for the case of a functional $\tilde \Phi$ with

$$ \tilde \Phi(v) = \int_M \tilde \phi(v(x),x)\,dx $$

with a function $\tilde \phi$ that depends on $x$. Obviously, such functionals are still convex.

**Q**: If $\tilde \phi(\,\cdot\,,x)$ is non-negative and convex for every $x$, then $\tilde \Phi$ is lsc., see e.g. [Modern Methods in the Calculus of Variations: Lp Spaces](http://books.google.de/books?id=z-uLxBRPWxgC) (Theorem 6.49). If we additionally assume e.g. $\tilde \phi(x,0) = 0$, then $\tilde \Phi$ is proper. Does equivalence of the above three statements (with an additional dependence on $x$) also hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Corollary 3E in

> Rockafellar, R. Tyrrell. Integral functionals, normal integrands and measurable selections. Nonlinear operators and the calculus of variations (Summer School, Univ. Libre Bruxelles, Brussels, 1975), pp. 157--207. Lecture Notes in Math., Vol. 543, Springer, Berlin, 1976. [DOI: 10.1007/bfb0079944](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/bfb0079944)

the conditions (1) and (2) are equivalent for any *proper normal convex integrand*.